# Unable to inject with unity a complex type to web api 2

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, dependency-injection, unity-container, asp.net-web-api2

I have a complex type to inject into a webapi controller and I am unable to resolve this dependency

```
 public class MyController(IMyComplexType)
```

The implementation of `IMyComplexType` has at least 5 dependencies `I1, ... I5`(so its implementation recieve `I1...I5`)

I have a Bootstrapper class to Register all dependencies, below a snippet of code to show you

```
    public class Bootstrapper
    {
        public static IUnityContainer ConfigureContainer(ref IUnityContainer container)
        {
            container.RegisterType<IMyComplexType, MyComplexTypeImplementation>
            (
              new HierarchicalLifetimeManager()
            );

            //Registering I1...I5 in the same way with their implementations
        }
     }
```

I tried to Load the Assmebly directly, so I1...I5 reside in assembly1, at the begining of my `ConfigureContainer` method

```
Assembly.Load("assembly1");
```

Also I have a UnityResolver copied from: [WebApi dependency injection](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/advanced/dependency-injection)

This is my WebApiConfig:

```
 public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            IUnityContainer container = new UnityContainer();
            Bootstrapper.ConfigureContainer(ref container);
            config.DependencyResolver = new UnityResolver(container);

            // Web API routes
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
```

I tried also to remove the injecton constructor on my controller and inside the Post method put something like this:

```
var service = Container.Resolve<IMyComplexType>() or var service = Container.Resolve<MyComplexTypeImplementation>()
```

I am losing something here?

Comment: You have to register the injectionconstructor types first, this means before you register IMyComplexType.
And I cannot see the registration for your controller
`c.registertype<IMyController,MyController>(new InjectionConstructor(typeof(IMyComplexType)));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Register all constructor types first and then the rest.

```
HttpContext.Current.Application.SetContainer(container);
container.AddNewExtension<Interception>();
c.RegisterType<IYourType,YourType>();
...
futher constructor types here
...
c.RegisterType<IMyComplexType,MyComplexType>();

c.RegisterType<IMyController, MyController>(
            new HierarchicalLifetimeManager(), 
            new InjectionConstructor(typeof(IMyComplexType)));
```

and then

```
public static class WebApiBootstrapper
    {
        public static void Init(IUnityContainer container)
        {
            GlobalConfiguration.Configure(config =>
            {
                config.DependencyResolver = new WebApiDependencyResolver(container); // DI container for use in WebApi
                config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
                WebApiRouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
            });
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why is important the order? At the end all types go to a dictionary(key, value) and it resolves the type from there, if the Key is present

Comment: it is not, did u get it to work?
The important thing is controller registration that u have to consider.

Comment: Yes is working now, but I didn't need to register the controller. Just the subsequent dependencies. So I1 was depending on R1, also R1 needs to be registered. I remove this line and is working too new InjectionConstructor(typeof(IMyComplexType)) for controller registration. But IMyComplexType needs to be present on the Container as part of the registration types

Comment: to bratko ;-) Ok, possible, I didn't take a look at the WebApiDependencyResolver class, usually u have to provide an InjectionConstructor, perhaps the DependencyResolver does that for you.