# Unable to inject DBContext into my Web API 2 Controller with Unity

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, dependency-injection, asp.net-web-api2, unity-container

I've been at it for days, but I can't get Unity to inject anything with `RegisterType<>` into my `Controller`. I'm using Web Api 2, in Visual Studio 2015, with Unity 4. Whenever I try to inject `IUnitOfWork` or `IRFContext`, I get   `"message": "An error occurred when trying to create a controller of type 'ClPlayersController'. Make sure that the controller has a parameterless public constructor."`.
I'm using the `Unity.AspNet.WebApi` to bootstrapp into WebApi. Below is my `UnityWebApiActivator`

```
[assembly: WebActivatorEx.PreApplicationStartMethod(typeof(mycompany.project.api.UnityWebApiActivator), "Start")]
[assembly: WebActivatorEx.ApplicationShutdownMethod(typeof(mycompany.project.api.UnityWebApiActivator), "Shutdown")]

namespace mycompany.project.api
{
    public static class UnityWebApiActivator
    {
        public static void Start() 
        {
            var resolver = new UnityDependencyResolver(UnityConfig.GetConfiguredContainer());
            GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = resolver;
        }

        public static void Shutdown()
        {
            var container = UnityConfig.GetConfiguredContainer();
            container.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

I'm using a Start.cs due to Owin.

```
[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(mycompany.project.api.Startup))]
namespace mycompany.project.api
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration();

            ConfigureOAuth(app);

            config.DependencyResolver = new UnityDependencyResolver(UnityConfig.GetConfiguredContainer());
            WebApiConfig.Register(config);
            app.UseCors(Microsoft.Owin.Cors.CorsOptions.AllowAll);
            app.UseWebApi(config);
        }

        public void ConfigureOAuth(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions OAuthServerOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions()
            {
                AllowInsecureHttp = true,
                TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/token"),
                AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(1),
                Provider = new SimpleAuthorizationServerProvider(),
                RefreshTokenProvider = new SimpleRefreshTokenProvider()
            };

            // Token Generation
            app.UseOAuthAuthorizationServer(OAuthServerOptions);
            app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions());

        }
    }
}
```

My `WebApiConfig.cs` is below:

```
namespace mycompany.project.api
{
    public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
            config.EnableSystemDiagnosticsTracing();
            config.Services.Add(typeof(IExceptionLogger),
                new SimpleExceptionLogger(new LogManagerAdapter()));
            config.Services.Replace(typeof(IExceptionHandler), new GlobalExceptionHandler());
        }
    }
}
```

My `UnityConfig.cs` is below

```
namespace mycompany.project.api
{
    public class UnityConfig
    {
        #region Unity Container
        private static Lazy<IUnityContainer> container = new Lazy<IUnityContainer>(() =>
        {
            var container = new UnityContainer();
            RegisterTypes(container);
            return container;
        });

        public static IUnityContainer GetConfiguredContainer()
        {
            return container.Value;
        }
        #endregion

        public static void RegisterTypes(IUnityContainer container)
        {
            var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
            {
                                //AutoMapper bindings
            });
            container.RegisterInstance<IMapper>(config.CreateMapper());
            container.RegisterType<IRFContext, RFContext>(new PerThreadLifetimeManager());
            container.RegisterType<IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork>();
            XmlConfigurator.Configure();
            var logManager = new LogManagerAdapter();
            container.RegisterInstance<ILogManager>(logManager);
        }
    }
}
```

All that I have in my `Global.asax` is below:

```
public class WebApiApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Error()
    {
        var exception = Server.GetLastError();
        if (exception != null)
        {
            var log = new LogManagerAdapter().GetLog(typeof(WebApiApplication));
            log.Error("Unhandled exception.", exception);
        }
    }
}
```

If my Controller is like this, it works fine:

```
public class ClPlayersController : ApiController
{
    private readonly IMapper mapper;

    public ClPlayersController(IMapper _mapper, IUnityContainer container)
    {
        mapper = _mapper;
    }
```

But placing IUnitOfWork, like below, or the IRFContext, I get the error:

```
    private readonly IMapper mapper;
    private readonly IUnitOfWork unitOfWork;

    public ClPlayersController(IMapper _mapper, IUnityContainer container, IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork)
    {
        mapper = _mapper;
        unitOfWork = _unitOfWork;
    }
```

I can't find, for the life of me, what I'm doing wrong. If I loop through the `container.Registrations` on the constructor, I find the mappings, but they refuse to get injected. Any hints?

**EDIT**

Below is the code for UnitOfWork and RFContext

```
namespace mycompany.project.data.configuracao
{
    public class UnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork
    {
        private readonly IRFContext _rfContext;
        private bool _disposed = false;

        public UnitOfWork(IRFContext rfContext)
        {
            _rfContext = rfContext;
        }
        public void Commit()
        {
            if (_disposed)
            {
                throw new ObjectDisposedException(this.GetType().FullName);
            }

            _rfContext.SaveChanges();
        }
        public void Dispose()
        {
            Dispose(true);
            GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
        }

        protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (_disposed) return;

            if (disposing && _rfContext != null)
            {
                _rfContext.Dispose();
            }

            _disposed = true;
        }
    }
}
```

and

```
namespace mycompany.project.data.configuracao
{
    public interface IUnitOfWork : IDisposable
    {
        void Commit();
    }
}
```

and RFContext is a basic POCO generated DBContext

```
namespace mycompany.project.data.configuracao
{
    using System.Linq;

    public class RFContext : System.Data.Entity.DbContext, IRFContext
    {
        public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<ClGrupoEconomico> ClGrupoEconomicoes { get; set; }
                //all my DbSets
        public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<SpTipoLog> SpTipoLogs { get; set; }

        static RFContext()
        {
            System.Data.Entity.Database.SetInitializer<RFContext>(null);
        }

        public RFContext()
            : base("Name=RFContext")
        {
        }

        public RFContext(string connectionString)
            : base(connectionString)
        {
        }

        public RFContext(string connectionString, System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbCompiledModel model)
            : base(connectionString, model)
        {
        }

        public RFContext(System.Data.Common.DbConnection existingConnection, bool contextOwnsConnection)
            : base(existingConnection, contextOwnsConnection)
        {
        }

        public RFContext(System.Data.Common.DbConnection existingConnection, System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbCompiledModel model, bool contextOwnsConnection)
            : base(existingConnection, model, contextOwnsConnection)
        {
        }

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(System.Data.Entity.DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

            modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new ClGrupoEconomicoConfiguration());
                        //all my Configuration classes
            modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new SpTipoLogConfiguration());
        }

        public static System.Data.Entity.DbModelBuilder CreateModel(System.Data.Entity.DbModelBuilder modelBuilder, string schema)
        {
            modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new ClGrupoEconomicoConfiguration(schema));
                        //all my configuration classes
            modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new SpTipoLogConfiguration(schema));
            return modelBuilder;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you share your code for `UnitOfWork` and `RFContext`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately the exception you are seeing can occur for several reasons. One of them is when `Unity` cannot resolve one or more of your injections.

> An error occurred when trying to create a controller of type
>   'FooController'. Make sure that the controller has a parameterless
>   public constructor.

So, based on the information in your question your setup is apparently correct, since `IMapper` can be injected. Therefore I *guess* that `UnitOfWork` and `RFContext` have dependencies that `Unity` cannot resolve. Maybe a repository?

**UPDATE:**

The problem here is that your `RFContext` has several constructors.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc440940.aspx#cnstrctinj_multiple

> When a target class contains more than one constructor with the same
>   number of parameters, you must apply the InjectionConstructor
>   attribute to the constructor that the Unity container will use to
>   indicate which constructor the container should use. As with automatic
>   constructor injection, you can specify the constructor parameters as a
>   concrete type, or you can specify an interface or base class for which
>   the Unity container contains a registered mapping.

In this case Unity doesn't know how to resolve your `RFContext`, and will try to use the constructor with the most parameters. You can solve it by using

```
container.RegisterType<IRFContext, RFContext>(new InjectionConstructor());
```

Comment: I've added the code. RFContext is just a basic POCO generated DBContext, and UnitOfWork loads it. I think is related to this issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30397188/unable-to-inject-with-unity-a-complex-type-to-web-api-2 . However, I couldn't pinpoint what I'm doing wrong with the sequence of registration. Anything with RegisterType doesn't work. Thanks so much for your help..

Comment: YOU'RE MY HERO! It worked. How do I use the InjectionConstructor together with the PerThreadLifetimeManager? THANK YOU SO MUCH!

Comment: I got it
            container.RegisterType<IRFContext, RFContext>(new PerThreadLifetimeManager(), new InjectionConstructor());
Thank so, so much for your help and coding wisdom!